# How to activate function lists in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

The question might sound stupid.

I am using NP++ 6.8.8 (the latest I addording the homepage)

I would like to use the function list (basically as described [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/function-list.html)), with 
nothing special, just to see PHP-functions.

I can open the function list window, but don't see any functions.

Do I need to do something to get this working?

The functionList.XML - in the NPP installation directory - looks OK. And I have not used function lists it until now, but know it worked some time back.

PS:

not even this helped [Notepad++ function list PHP not working if I didn't close the PHP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101807/notepad-function-list-php-not-working-if-i-didnt-close-the-php-tag)

Comment: Same thing for me with php script :( but it works with other language. You could ask your question in Npp forum: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: I posted it in the NPP forum as well. (but expected to get a quicker answer here.

I just made a quick test with a python file, but this didn't work either.

Comment: The answer might sound stupid, but maybe this is what you 're looking for: go to menu View -> Function List

Comment: It's been the solution is described below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functionList.xml in the %APPDATA% (= C:\Documents and Settings\< User >\< App Data >\Notepad++) need to be deleted (or renamed).

This file only containes a three languages, while the file in the Program directory contains many more languages.

In addition the link to [Notepad++ function list PHP not working if I didn't close the PHP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101807/notepad-function-list-php-not-working-if-i-didnt-close-the-php-tag) was helpful as well.

NPP Ref:

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11285/how-to-activate-function-lists-in-notepad

Comment: Note that removing **functionList.xml** from the "backend" folder (in my case, **C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++**) only once may not be enough.

After you edited **functionList.xml** in the NPP installation folder, it is copied to the backend, and the next editing would not change it in the backend. So, every time you want to modify **functionList.xml**, you need remove it from the backend.

Comment: What a crazy bug to ship with the right function list file, but in the wrong place for it to work

Comment: Each time `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\functionList.xml` is removed, it is being AUTOMATICALLY REPLACED by an exact copy of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\functionList.xml` at the next program start of NP++.

Comment: it is not created %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\functionList.xml anymore after npp launched