# How to show python methods in notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

How to show available methods in Notepad++?
I mean this option from Visual Studio:

[image]

I want to see the same in Notepad++

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to activate function lists in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341004/how-to-activate-function-lists-in-notepad)

Comment: I don't believe that Notepad++ can do this and I'm a little baffled that you expect that it should. Notepad++ is a text editor, not an IDE. It can handle a large number of programming languages but its support is mostly limited to syntax highlighting, which is the sort of thing that a generic tool can offer. The pop-ups you want require the environment to understand that the identifier at the cursor is an object, and how to look up the attributes of that object, which is of course different for every supported language.

Comment: Notepadd++ is a text editor. You request feature of development environment. Text editors (NPP) are simple and lack programming features. Development environment will provide all the fancy features for programmers.