# How to fix functionList.xml is not processed problem?

Tags: notepad++

I want to use the function list functionality for .txt files. If a line start with H1, H2, ..., then I want to see it in the function list. It would help me in navigation.

I deleted `functionList.xml` from both `Program Files\Notepad++\` and `AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\`. I created a simple `functionList.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<NotepadPlus>
    <functionList>
        <associationMap>
            <association id=    "txt_syntax"    ext=".txt" />
        </associationMap>
        <parsers>
            <parser
                id         ="txt_syntax"
                displayName="txt_syntax"> 
                <function mainExpr="^(H1|H2|H3|H4|H5).*$">
                </function>
            </parser>  
        </parsers>
    </functionList>
</NotepadPlus>
```

The function list panel is empty. I tried the ideas of [How to activate function lists in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35341004/5852947)  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you use "Setting on the cloud" option (Setting->Preferences->Cloud->Set your cloud location path here) then you should edit "functionList.xml" at this location.

The "functionList.xml" files from "%ProgramFiles%" and "%APPDATA%\notepad++" don't take effect in this case.